# map whole array if value equal

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to map an array where if one of the values equal to a variable then I change the isChecked key for all objects in this array. for e.g.

input array:

```
[
  [
    {
      "name": "size",
      "value": "XS",
      "isChecked": false
    },
    {
      "name": "colors",
      "value": "black",
      "isChecked": false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "size",
      "value": "XXXL",
      "isChecked": false
    },
    {
      "name": "colors",
      "value": "brown",
      "isChecked": false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "size",
      "value": "S",
      "isChecked": false
    },
    {
      "name": "colors",
      "value": "green",
      "isChecked": false
    }
  ]
]
```

input value: black

output:

```
[
  [
    {
      "name": "size",
      "value": "XS",
      "isChecked": true
    },
    {
      "name": "colors",
      "value": "black",
      "isChecked": true
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "size",
      "value": "XXXL",
      "isChecked": false
    },
    {
      "name": "colors",
      "value": "brown",
      "isChecked": false
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "size",
      "value": "S",
      "isChecked": false
    },
    {
      "name": "colors",
      "value": "green",
      "isChecked": false
    }
  ]
]
```

maybe should i use some callback,promise? How to map this array? I have to somehow return to the value I missed. In this case, if the value in the array is found then all elements in this array should be marked as isChecked = true.

i've got something like this now:

```
this.allVariants.map((variant, key) => {

                return variant.map((opts, k) => {

                    if (opts.value == val && !opts.isChecked) {
                        let mapped = variant.map(op => op.isChecked = true);
                    } else {
                        let mapped = variant.map(op => op.isChecked = false);
                    }

                    return opts
                })
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map` method and inside `some` to check if element exists in sub-array or not.

```js
const data = [[{"name":"size","value":"XS","isChecked":false},{"name":"colors","value":"black","isChecked":false}],[{"name":"size","value":"XXXL","isChecked":false},{"name":"colors","value":"brown","isChecked":false}],[{"name":"size","value":"S","isChecked":false},{"name":"colors","value":"green","isChecked":false}]]

const res = data.map(arr => {
  const check = arr.some(({value}) => value == 'black');
  return check ? arr.map(e => ({...e, isChecked: true})) : arr
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Instead of `array.find`, you can use `array.some`. Also renaming `check` to `isCheck` would reduce some typing and would make more sense

Comment: Also, `==`? Its been ages seeing someone use it for string comparison.

Comment: What else would you use for string comparison? Unless you mean strict equality (`===`) the equality operator is just the thing for the job. This isn't Java where you have to do `value.equals("black")` or probably even `"black".equals(value)` to avoid potential NPEs. EDIT: although I suppose you might want to do `value.localeCompare("black")` but that's usually for ordering. A locale aware case-insensitive comparison using `value.toLocaleLowercase() == "black"` is still fine and pretty wide spread.

Comment: it's works but i have a question. how to map result only for first true check? other true should be omitted/false

Comment: You could use one variable and set it to true on first match https://jsfiddle.net/sfu9kt5h/82/, if you don't want to change original data, otherwise just use find and that will give you reference to first matched sub-array if found

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this? As you can see there's a simple `map` function which will return an array of the relevant values depending on what was input into the function. It will simply map over the provided arrray and update the relevant objects, provided that the `find` function doesn't return null.

It achieves this by seeing if the provided value can be found within a nested array via using the `found` function that I've implemented, provided this returns true, it will then use the `mutate` function. The idea was that you **may** want to further change different properties on the given object(s) in future, hence why it has a dedicated function.

My answer is similar to @NenadVracar only I broke it up a little more into multiple functions that consume a single line.

```js
let data = [[{name:"size",value:"XS",isChecked:!1},{name:"colors",value:"black",isChecked:!1}],[{name:"size",value:"XXXL",isChecked:!1},{name:"colors",value:"brown",isChecked:!1}],[{name:"size",value:"S",isChecked:!1},{name:"colors",value:"green",isChecked:!1}]];

// A function that states if relevant object with value exists.
let found = v => a => a.some(({value}) => value == v);

// A function used to return data that has been changed, specifically isChecked = true.
let mutate = a => a.map(i => ({...i, isChecked: true}));

// A function to return the desired array, takes an array and a value. 
let map = v => a => a.map(o => found(v)(o) ? mutate(o) : o);

console.log(map('black')(data));
```